# How do i show this :$\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\frac{h²+3h+3}{(h+1)\sqrt{1+h}+1}-2$ for $h\neq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I would like to show this formula is true for $h\neq 0$, where $f$ is defined for $x \in \mathbb{R^*+}$ as follow :$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{x}$

$$\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}=\frac{h²+3h+3}{(h+1)\sqrt{1+h}+1}-2$$

**Attempt** :I have used the notion of derivability where LHS equal's to $f'(1)=\frac{-1}{2}$, and the second where $h$ go to $0$ it is the same
Is it this enough to say that the above equality is satisfied ?

Thank you for any help

Comment: No, this only shows that the two sides have the same limit as $h \to 0$. Showing the equality has nothing to do with limits per se, it's simply an algebraic manipulation. (Probably this amounts to multiplying by the conjugate of the numerator.)

Comment: in the fact i did this but the numerator will be complicated for calculation

Comment: Multiplying by the conjugate show simplify the expression. If you've already done this, multiply both numerator and denominator by $h^b$ for an appropriate power $b$ to clear any "fractions within fractions".

Comment: I multiplied by the conjugate of denomunator I have got :(1+h)^3 , i have used taylor expansion to obtain 1+3h at the point h=0

Comment: Are you sure you have the right $f$? The right expression for the difference quotient?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{f(h+1) - f(1)}{h} = \frac{\frac{1}{h+1} + \sqrt{h+1} - 2}{h}= \frac{\frac{1}{h+1} - 1}{h} + \frac{\sqrt{h+1}- 1}{h}= \frac{-h}{h(h+1)} + \frac{h+1-1}{h(\sqrt{h+1}+1)} = \frac{-1}{h+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{h+1}+1} $

$\frac{-1}{h+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{h+1}+1} = \frac{h - \sqrt{h+1}}{(h+1)(\sqrt{h+1}+1)} = \frac{h^2 - h - 1}{(h+1)(\sqrt{h+1}+1)(h + \sqrt{h+1})}$

I think the equality you have is false since if you let $h \rightarrow 0 $ you should get $\frac{-1}{2}$ but in the case above you get $\frac{3}{2}$.

After the editing.

$\dfrac{ \frac{1}{1+h} + \sqrt{h+1} -2}{h} = \dfrac{h+1 - \left(2 - \frac{1}{h+1} \right)^2}{h \left(\sqrt{h+1} +2 - \frac{1}{h+1} \right) } = \dfrac{h+1 - 4 + \frac{4}{h+1} - \frac{1}{(1+h)^2}}{h \left(\sqrt{h+1} +2 - \frac{1}{h+1} \right)}$

Multiply with $(1+h)^2$

$\dfrac{(h+1)^3 - 4 (1+h)^2 + 4 (h+1) - 1}{h(h+1)( (\sqrt{h+1})^3 + 2 (\sqrt{h+1})^2 - 1 )}$

Note that $x^3 - 4x^2 + x - 1 = (x-1)(x^2 - 3x +1), x^3 + 2x^2 -1 = (x+1)(x^2 +x -1)$
Hence 
$\dfrac{(h+1-1)((h+1)^2 -3 (h+1) +1)}{h(h+1)(\sqrt{h+1} +1)(h+1 + \sqrt{h+1} -1)}$

After some simplification we get the same result above

$\dfrac{h^2 - h - 1}{(h+1)(\sqrt{h+1}+1)(h + \sqrt{h+1})}$ it seems there is a mistake although the limit as $h\rightarrow 0$ is the same

Comment: Thank you , i edited it now as it is montioned in the scholar book of Bac

Comment: I edited it but still i cant reach the expression in the question